# How to change column value to match row based on column condition

Tags: r, dplyr

In this dummy dataset, I'd like to change the "value" column for each site to the value where "type" is "home".

```
a <- structure(list(site = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), value = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6), type = c("home", "away", "home", "away", "home", 
"away")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, I'd like to end up with this:

```
site    value    type
a       1        home
a       1        away
b       3        home
b       3        away
c       5        home
c       5        away
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, for each site, changes the number in the `value` column to the value when `type == "home"`:

```
a %>% dplyr::group_by(site) %>% dplyr::mutate(value = first(value[type=="home"]))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   site [3]
  site  value type 
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 a         1 home 
2 a         1 away 
3 b         3 home 
4 b         3 away 
5 c         5 home 
6 c         5 away
```

Comment: When running this on my real data, I'm getting the error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `value`.
i `value = value[type == "home"]`.
i `value` must be size 68 or 1, not 11.

Comment: I don't know what that means because everything in the data seems to make sense

Comment: Can you post a sample of your real data please? I'll try and address the issue.

Comment: Try it now. Wrapping the vector around some aggregate function is always safe.

Answer (score 1):

> When running this on my real data, I'm getting the error ...

One guess: It may be that there isn't a unique value for each `site` and `type` equal to "home". One could add `distinct()` after `select(site, value)` in the second approach below to ensure that this is the case.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <-
    structure(list(
        site = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
        value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
        type = c("home", "away", "home", "away", "home", "away")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L),
    class = "data.frame")

# From answer above
df %>% 
    group_by(site) %>% 
    mutate(value = value[type=="home"])
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   site [3]
#>   site  value type 
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 a         1 home 
#> 2 a         1 away 
#> 3 b         3 home 
#> 4 b         3 away 
#> 5 c         5 home 
#> 6 c         5 away

# A more "SQL-like" approach
df %>%
    filter(type == "home") %>%
    select(site, value) %>%
    inner_join(df %>% select(site, type), by = "site")
#>   site value type
#> 1    a     1 home
#> 2    a     1 away
#> 3    b     3 home
#> 4    b     3 away
#> 5    c     5 home
#> 6    c     5 away
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We may also use `match` to find the first position if there is any

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
    group_by(site) %>%
     mutate(value = value[match("home", type)]) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  site  value type 
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 a         1 home 
2 a         1 away 
3 b         3 home 
4 b         3 away 
5 c         5 home 
6 c         5 away
```